# Reading the checked boxes value on submit using typescript on angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

In my user details update page. I'm getting the user roles from the server and fetch on a form check box control using the following line of codes.

```
<div id="user_role" class="checkbox" *ngFor="let role of roles">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox"
             value="{{role.id}}"
             [checked]="user_roles_ids.indexOf(role.id) !== -1"
             (change)="getCheckBoxValue($event.target.getAttribute('value'),
             $event.target.checked)"
             >{{ role.role_name }}
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now my problem is how do i read this values from on a button click event. I have achieved to read the values while user change the check box values. But If user doesn't touch the roles and update other fields and press the submit button. I could not able to read the checked values on my form controllers.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're just putting input elements into the template.

You probably want to use the NgForm directive, which allows tracking of changes and submits. The second link has a short example that should get you started, while the first link is a more comprehensive guide.

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html - A short official guide on forms in Angular 2.
- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/NgForm-directive.html - Documentation for NgForm.